# Console app in yii fails to include AR model

Tags: php, yii, command, console-application

I want to schedule to run console command in yii.
I composed php script and tried it in web-app - works well.
Yet, when i put it as [console command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.console) the cron send the following message:

```
PHP Error[2]: include(User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    in file /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/YiiBase.php at line 427
#0 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/YiiBase.php(427): autoload()
#1 unknown(0): autoload()
#2 /home/srv50213/htdocs/doc/protected/commands/ReportMailerCommand.php(20): spl_autoload_call()
#3 unknown(0): ReportMailerCommand->actionIndex2()
#4 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/console/CConsoleCommand.php(172): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#5 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(71): ReportMailerCommand->run()
#6 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/console/CConsoleApplication.php(92): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#7 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#8 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/yiic.php(33): CConsoleApplication->run()
#9 /home/srv50213/htdocs/doc/protected/yiic.php(8): require_once()
```

Seems like autoload() does not function properly.
For console app $config i use config/console.php where i've inserted the db setting (from main.php and user setting).

```
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(            
            // настройки для конфигурации 
        'connectionString' => 
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
        'username' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'yiiapp_', 
        'class'     => 'CDbConnection'          
    ),
    'user'=>array(      
        'class' => 'WebUser', 
        //'class' => 'application.components.User',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),  
 )
```

The script is smth. like this:

```
public function actionIndex2($args) 
{    
    $users = User::model()->findAllByPk( array(177) );  
    foreach($users as $user)
    {         
        $query = "SELECT  e.id, e.Subject
                        FROM  `yiiapp_doc_events` AS e
                        LEFT JOIN  `yiiapp_doc_event_users` AS u ON e.id = u.eventId
                        WHERE e.StatusId NOT IN (5,7)  
                        AND u.userId = {$user->id}
                        GROUP BY e.id";
        $queryResult = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll(); 

        if ($queryResult)
        {   
            foreach($queryResult as $res)
            {
                $i++;
                $link = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('docEvents/update', array('id'=>$res['id']));
                $table .= "<tr><td> {$i} </td><td> <a href='{$link}'>{$res['id']}</a> </td><td> <a href='{$link}'>{$res['Subject']}</a> </td></tr>";                
            }
            //echo $table . '</table>';
            $content= "  $table . '</table>';
            mail($user->email,  "Report (". $i . ')', $content,  'Content-type: text/html');
        }
    } 
}
```

What's wrong, how to fix it?

## Update

As suggested by *chris* i've added the import parameter in config array.
Now that issue is gone. Yet since i call for `Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl()` the other thing frustrates `Undefined index: SERVER_NAME`:

```
PHP Error[8]: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME
in file /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php at line 317
#0 /home/srv50213/htdocs/framework/base/CApplication.php(560): CHttpRequest->getHostInfo()
#1 /home/srv50213/htdocs/doc/protected/commands/ReportMailerCommand.php(39): CConsoleApplication->createAbsoluteUrl()
...
```

What's the solution?

## Solution

After some googling for createAbsoluteUrl in console command i found useful threads [1](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14825-problem-with-createurl-and-createabsoluteurl-in-console-application/page__view__findpost__p__117209) and [2](https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=2638#c2).

The first gives this remedy - add following in config/console.php:

```
'components' => array(
     'request' => array(
        'hostInfo' => 'https://domainname.com',
        'baseUrl' => '',
        'scriptUrl' => '',
     ),
     ...
)
```

And second way is similar:

```
'components' => array(
    'urlManager' => array(
        'baseUrl' => 'https://domain.com'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the import correctly defined? I think it's not default in console config.
Put something like this in it:

```
'import' => array(
    'application.models.*',
),
```

**Edit: to your update:**
You cannot use `createUrl()` function in a console application. Like you have found, it uses `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, which is not set, since console app always runs without a server, directly by php cli.

Comment: the `createUrl()` deals with relative paths urls, not depending on `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` like `/doc/index.php?r=admin`, while `createAbsoluteUrl()` does depend on server info. So the support has been added for `createUrl()` in console command in yii:
https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/CHANGELOG?spec=svn3350&r=3350#70